# Using sed to insert a value into a line after match

Tags: bash, sed

I'm looking to get an argument inserted into a variable, sed currently pouting at me.

Turning this:

```
BASHVAR=" -Java.args -More.Java.Args -Even.More Java Args"
```

To this:

```
BASHVAR=" -Newly.added.Java.args -Java.args -More.Java.Args -Even.More Java Args"
```

I've tried matching and appending, but it adds newlines:

```
sed '/-Java.args/i -Newly.added.Java.args' /path-to-file
```

Resulting in:

```
-Newly.added.Java.args
BASHVAR=" -Java.args -More.Java.Args -Even.More Java Args"
```

Doesn't have to be sed, but would be nice use it.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use substitution instead of insertion

```
s/-Java.args/-Newly.added.Java.args &/
```

Comment: Oh my god, completely brainfarted about the &. Hero thanks!